# SharePoint Publishing page editing issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have all the proper permissions on site and I am trying to edit/Update content with Table, Image and other formatting on publishing page in SharePoint 2013 and having issues: The issue is when I tried to apply formatting on content the cursor is jumping/Moving on the page. I am not sure but recently observed this behavior. Can you please let me know how I can avoid this jumping issue.

Answer (score 0):

How do you apply formatting on content? Using the "Format Text" in the ribbon?

For narrowing down your issue, test below things:

Test in IE 32-bit.

Run in safe mode and see if it works

Clean your browser Cache and Cookies.

Test in another browser like Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Yes using Format Text in the ribbon

Comment: Have you test above things? Maybe this is an issue about compatibility.